# Using mmap() instead of malloc()

Tags: c, malloc, mmap

I am trying to complete an exercise that is done with system calls and need to allocate memory for a struct *. My code is:

```
myStruct * entry = (myStruct *)mmap(0, SIZEOF(myStruct), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

To clarify, I cannot use `malloc()` but can use `mmap()`. I was having no issues with this on Windows in Netbeans, now however I'm compiling and running from command line on Ubuntu I am getting "Segmentation Fault" each time I try to access it.

Is there a reason why it will work on one and not the other, and is `mmap()` a valid way of allocating memory in this fashion? My worry was I was going to be allocating big chunks of memory for each `mmap()` call initially, now I just cannot get it to run.

Additionally, the error returned my mmap is 22 - Invalid Argument (I did some troubleshooting while writing the question so the error check isn't in the above code). Address is 0, the custom `SIZEOF()` function works in other mmap arguments, I am using `MAP_ANONYMOUS` so the `fd` and `offset`parameters must -1 and 0 respectively.

Is there something wrong with the `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE` sections?

Comment: Just a wild guess, if you use `4096` or `8192` or some other power of two instead of `SIZEOF(myStruct)`, does it work ?

Comment: I think the error is from your `SIZEOF()`. and you should add `MAP PRIVATE`

Comment: the `SIZEOF()`  is not correct  the actual item is spelled `sizeof()`  I.E. all lower case.

Comment: the first parameter to `mmap()` is an address pointer, not an integer,  Strongly suggest using `NULL` rather than `0`

Comment: Please, _always_ make a complete, compilable example - an [MCVE]. Always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify MAP_PRIVATE in your flags.

```
myStruct * entry = (myStruct *)mmap(0, SIZEOF(myStruct),
        PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

From the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap):

> The flags argument determines whether updates to the mapping are
>   visible to other processes mapping the same region, and whether
>   updates are carried through to the underlying file. This behavior is
>   determined by **including exactly one** of the following values in flags:

You need exactly one of the flags MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED - but you didn't give either of them.

A complete example:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} myStruct;

int main()
{
    myStruct * entry = (myStruct *)mmap(0, sizeof(myStruct),
            PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    if (entry == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Map failed.\n");
    }
    else {
        entry->a = 4;
        printf("Success: entry=%p, entry->a = %d\n", entry, entry->a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(The above, without `MAP_PRIVATE` of course, is a good example of what you might have provided as a an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This makes it much easier for others to help you, since they can see exactly what you've done, and test their proposed solutions. You should always provide an MCVE).

Comment: This was it, I misread the manual! I started with MAP_PRIVATE, moved to MAP_ANONYMOUS, needed both... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The man page for `mmap()` says that you must specify exactly one of `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_PRIVATE` in the `flags` argument.  In your case, to act like `malloc()`, you'll want `MAP_PRIVATE`:

```
myStruct *entry = mmap(0, sizeof *entry,
                       PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

(I've also made this more idiomatic C by omitting the harmful cast and matching the `sizeof` to the actual variable rather than its type).